# Slider doesn't work margin-left: 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm studying jQuery and I did this simple code below to animate three images like a slideshow. The problem is when the last image is showered the code was supposed to go back do margin-left 0 and start the slide again but it isn't working.

```js
$(function() {

   var width = 809;
   var animationSpeed = 1000;
   var pause = 1000; 
   var currentSlide = 1;

   var $slideContainer = $("#slideshow .slides");
   var $slide = $("#slideshow .slide");


   setInterval(function() {   
   $slideContainer.animate({ 'margin-left': '-='+width }, animationSpeed, function(){
    $("#console").html("Posicao: "+currentSlide);
    currentSlide++;    
    if (currentSlide === $slide.length){
     currentSlide = 1;
     $slideContainer.css('margin-left: ', 0);
    } 
   });
  }, pause); 
  });
```

```css
  #slideshow {   
   width: 809px;
   height: 449px;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  #slideshow .slides {
   display: block;
   width: 3236px;
   height: 449px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  #slideshow .slide {
   float: left;
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 809px;
   height: 449px;
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
<ul class="slides">
 <li class="slide"><img src="teste1.jpg" /></li>
 <li class="slide"><img src="teste2.jpg" /></li>
 <li class="slide"><img src="teste3.jpg" /></li>
 <li class="slide"><img src="teste1.jpg" /></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$slideContainer.css('margin-left: ', 0); is incorrect
$slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0); correct
```

https://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Hey Yosvany, I changed but still not working. Did you find something wrong?